# Pass Recipient Field as an array

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an application, and i am using my own built API on Laravel. In my API, i have the coded below to receive recipients number in array form in my APIController below.

Now in my try to test out my API in the DocController, i keep getting the error.

> > pass recipients field as an array

In the DocController, i am passing recipient as an array already. What else i could be missing in my code below ?

**ApiController**

```
    public function gearCall(Request $request)
    {
    $recipients = $request->post('recipient');
    if (!is_array($recipients)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'pass recipients field as an array'
                ]);
                }
      }
```

**DocController**

```
public function testAPI(Request $request)
    {

        $endPoint = 'https://lara.codein.com/api/';
        $apiKey = '****';
        $url = $endPoint . '?key=' . $apiKey;
        $curlFile = curl_file_create('public/media/test.mp3');
        $data = [
           'recipient' => ['9082300239', '9052384200'],
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($data));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        curl_close($ch);
```

**When i print_r $data in DocController**

```
Array
(
    [recipient] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9082300239
            [1] => 9052384200

)
{"status":"error","message":"pass recipients field as an array"}
```

Comment: In your ApiController the line $recipients = $request->post('recipient'); where is $request being initiated? Have you checked the $request actually holds anything?

Comment: @Petay87 ,  check my update... Yes the request holds the data

Comment: What if you print_r($request) in the ApiController? We still haven't seen what $request holds what you expect it to.

Comment: Could you please post a print of $recipients

Comment: Also, check print_r($_POST["data"]). I think yours issue here is that you are looking at $request but that's not where the data is as you don't have Request $request in  public function gearCall(). Either change it to  public function gearCall(Request $request) or use  $recipients = $_POST['data'][0] ;

Comment: @Petay87, i have made changes in my code `public function gearCall(Request $request)` but i am getting the same response displayed in my question.

Comment: So now what is the output of print_r($request) and print_r($_POST) in the ApiController?

Comment: Could it also be i am using `http_build_query($data)` for header `$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";`

Comment: @Petay87, i am getting the same response as show in the question

Comment: I asked you to print_r($request) and print_r($_POST) in the ApiController. At the moment we are just working on the issue that it's not an array but we haven't actually checked that the data is there at all in the ApiController method yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell CURL that it's a HTTP POST request, try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```